# Altair doesn't display charts when running a script from terminal?

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, altair

I am following this tutorial example on my Mac Pro Big Sur.

```
https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/simple_bar_chart.html
```

vtest.py is below:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52]
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='a',
    y='b'
)
```

When I execute this on a terminal, it doesn't display anything, no visualization showing up, no error or warning message either.

```
% python vtest.py
```

Doesn't Altair work on Mac OS?

Comment: `entrypoints, toolz, numpy, jinja2, jsonschema, pandas`Just in case you've already installed these, right?

Comment: @r-beginners All dependencies are installed and the 'source' df can be printed out correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show an Altair plot by running a script from terminal, you can use the `.show()` method to open it in your default browser:

```
alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='a',
    y='b'
).show()
```

The docs include a section with [more details about how Altair charts are rendered and how to display them conveniently](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html), starting with this passage:

> Altair produces Vega-Lite visualizations, which require a Javascript frontend to display the charts. Because notebook environments combine a Python backend with a Javascript frontend, many users find them convenient for using Altair.